# Webpack - [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I've looked around, but can't get any of the answers I've seen on stackoverflow to work.

I cannot use the command line for webpack or the webpack dev-server; I am restricted to using the Node API.

Below is how I am using webpack.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    // i've also tried webpack/hot/dev-server here
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'js', 'app.jsx')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'js'),
    filename: 'script.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
    }]
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

**contained in a gulp task "start"**

```
gulp.task('start', function (callback) {
  var config = Object.create(require('webpack.config.js'));
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());

  var devServer = new webpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    stats: { colors: true },
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    progress: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true
  });
});
```

**What I expect**

When I run gulp start, I expect the webpack dev server to spin up, allowing me to hit localhost:3000/. This should load an index.html from my project's /dist/ folder. So far so good. I expect that when I make a change to a file (e.g., app.jsx), that the change would be present.

**What is actually happening**

I am getting the error "[HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled", with no further explanation.

Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to get hot reloading working for a full day.

Answer (score 1):

in your webpack.config.js on the plugins section try this,

```
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
```

I know you are pushing the plugin in your gulp task but you have to use `--hot --inline` on cli or on your npm script

Answer (score 1):

Try to run webpack as
`webpack-dev-server --hot --inline` in packge.json,
somehow official docs is wrong now.